# Japan - Over 180 Days in 1 Year As Temporary Visitor

Tags: japan, us-citizens, visa-free-entry, denial-of-entry, repeat-visits

I am a US citizen with a US passport who enters Japan with 90 day temporary visitor waiver. I usually stay around 85-87 days per 90 day temporary visitor waiver. I have a lot of savings, don't work in Japan, and mainly go to see the country and visit my girlfriend, so I don't do anything illegal.

**I've been to Japan 4 times:**

**Year #1**
1st: October 26 2017-January 20, 2018 (A couple days under 90 days)

2nd: April 2, 2018-June 28, 2018 (A couple days under 90 days
Total: Around 175 days

**Year #2**
3rd: October 26 2018-January 20, 2019 (A couple days under 90 days)

4th: March 10 2019 - June 6, 2019 (A couple days under 90 days)
Total: Around 175 days

**Note:** Immigration never said anything to me despite me staying almost the full 90 days per visit these 4 times.

I left Japan June 6 2019 to go to my home in USA for 1 month exactly and will return to Japan in 10 days July 7 2019. I  am worried of being denied entry and not given another 90 day temporary visitor visa waiver when I return because within the last year I already stayed 175 days and the year would "reset" on October 26, 2019.

I heard that the 180 day limit is not an official rule but I'm not sure how strictly it is enforced.

Is it likely I'll be denied by immigration or questioned? What information/documents should I bring to improve my chances of being permitted? Would an invitation letter from my girlfriend help at all?

I'm really concerned about being on a flight from USA to Tokyo (around 20 hours) only to be denied.

Comment: I’m no expert but I’d say that with every trip your risk of being denied entry increases dramatically. Do you really need to visit so frequently and for so long? A typical rule of thumb is to spend at least the same amount of time outside the country as in it. Do you have documents proving your financial state and ties to the US to show to Immigration?

Comment: It definitely will look fishy. Why don't you look for some potential immigration opportunities which will allow you to stay longer, such as by marriage?

Comment: Yeah, at this point you’re skating on very thin ice. Any entry could be the one which causes a denial and deportation and that would SUCK. Instead, why not meet her in Korea or Guam? Both are a ton of fun and easy for her to get to by a low cost carrier.

Comment: Given "plenty of savings" it may be a better strategy to make several short visits each year, picking times when your girlfriend can spend a lot of time with you or there are particular tourist activities you want to attend.

Comment: OP has not returned to clarify. Putting on hold for now.